Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1 problem
when i put flutter build apk
its give me that
BUILD FAILED in 5s Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            7.0s Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1 
flutter build apk
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.?.??.
     Searched in the following locations:
       
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            7.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1


flutter doctor
• No issues found!
please solve this for me
i dont know problem
i dont know problem
i dont know problem

I hope this answer will help you

they syes The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.0.
Because flutter_sixvalley_ecommerce requires SDK version >=3.2.1 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
